# Cómo sumar el value según opción escogida

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una etiqueta span que contiene un numero el cual quiero que pueda ser sumado según la opción escogida y el mismo número cambie dentro de la etiqueta sin tener que crear otra para el resultado.

```html
<select id="cantidades">
<option>1</option> <!-- Sumar 1 vez -->
<option>2</option> <!-- Sumar 2 veces -->
<option>3</option> <!-- etc... -->
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>

<span id="numero">$15.000</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el valor de **$15.000** es estático, simple mente multiplicas el valor del `select` por *15* y lo imprimes en la etiqueta `<span id="numero">$15.000</span>`, además de que debes agregar un el atributo `value` a cada opción, espero te funcione.

```js
var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidades');

cantidad.addEventListener('change', function(){

  var valor = Number(this.value);
  
 console.log(valor); 
 
 var resultado = 15 * valor;
 
 var mostrar = document.getElementById('numero');
 console.log(resultado);
 
 mostrar.innerText = '$'+resultado+'.000';
 
  

})
```

```html
<select id="cantidades">
<option value="1">1</option> <!-- Sumar 1 vez -->
<option value="2">2</option> <!-- Sumar 2 veces -->
<option value="3">3</option> <!-- etc... -->
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<span id="numero">$15.000</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVASCRIPT:

•Primero usamos un metodo en el SELECT que es el onchange() donde le pasaras un funcion que crearas en JS, este metodo te ayudara a realizar la accion cuando selecciones una opcion.

---

**--Modo Dinámico**
• En myFuncion() solo obtendremos los valores de cada etiqueta.
Usamos "parseInt()" para convertir valores String a Númericos.

•Finalmente realizamos el calculo y así como obtenemos el valor de la misma forma lo podemos enviar.
Recuerda que cada vez que seleccionas el valor se altera por lo que siempre se aumentara.

---

**--Modo Estático**
acá solo usamos una CONST en ves de VAR esto indica que solo se podra asignar un valor y este no podrá ser alterado, por lo que multiplicara por la cantidad seleccionada

```js
//modo dinamico
function myFuncion(){

   var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML);
   var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidades").value);

   var resultado = numero * n;

   document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = resultado ;
    
  }

//modo estatico
const numeroEstatico = parseInt(document.getElementById("numero2").innerHTML);

function myFuncionEstatico(){ 
   var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidades2").value);

   var resultado = numeroEstatico * n;

   document.getElementById("numero2").innerHTML = resultado ;
    
  }
```

```html
<h2> MODO DINAMICO </h2>
<select id="cantidades" onchange="myFuncion()" >
  <option value="1">1</option> <!-- Sumar 1 vez -->
  <option value="2" >2</option> <!-- Sumar 2 veces -->
  <option value="3" >3</option> <!-- etc... -->
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
  <option value="9" >9</option>
  <option value="10" >10</option>
 </select>

 <span>$</span><span id="numero">15000</span>
 <hr>
 <h2> MODO ESTATICO </h2>
 <select id="cantidades2" onchange="myFuncionEstatico()" >
  <option value="1">1</option> <!-- Sumar 1 vez -->
  <option value="2" >2</option> <!-- Sumar 2 veces -->
  <option value="3" >3</option> <!-- etc... -->
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
  <option value="9" >9</option>
  <option value="10" >10</option>
 </select>

 <span>$</span><span id="numero2">15000</span>
```